# Is it compulsary to validate your archive through itunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

It was my frist app and  i submitted my app without validating to app store will it create some problem or can validate it again and resubmit it?

Comment: It's optional, but it may give you some useful info if you run validation and it's not valid. You can run the validation even after uploading the build to iTunes, it doesn't change the binary in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit it without validation. If your application status in iTunes is "Waiting for Review", then don't worry. Because if it was improper, then it will not allow you.

Comment: yes its waiting for review thank u...

Answer (score 2):

No.. It's not compulsary. But it's good practice to do. If there are some issues with your archive than you will get it first before uploading and that will be very useful to you :). Otherwise you will get error in uploading progress. So it's always good to validate but again it's not compulsary.

Comment: yes wont forget in future ..thank u :)